# Why does streaming audio in Mobile Safari sometimes not have a scrubber bar?

Tags: audio, safari, ios

Usually, if I click a link to an mp3 in Safari on the iPhone, it will look something like this:

[image: scrubber bar]

But sometimes, it looks like this, with no scrubber bar:

[image: no scrubber bar]

What does this indicate about the difference between the files? Is it related to a server configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was the answer supplied by Rackspace Cloud Sites support:

> Our servers cannot stream media files
>   so opening a media file such as an mp3
>   would be played back using a method
>   called progressive download within a
>   browser or device.  The following
>   article describes progressive
>   downloading:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download
>
> Basically, the media player will
>   download the file from start to finish
>   and allows you to play the portion of
>   the file that has downloaded.  iOS
>   devices, like many other mobile
>   devices, are limited in memory so will
>   stop downloading the file after its
>   internal buffer is full so that it can
>   conserve what precious little RAM it
>   has available.  Though the download
>   stops, the device will continue to
>   play the portion of the media file it
>   has downloaded so far.  Once the
>   device gets near the end of the
>   downloaded data a new HTTP request is
>   sent to resume downloading of the
>   media file so that playback is
>   uninterrupted.  Once the download of
>   new data resumes, the cycle starts
>   again with the device pausing when its
>   buffer is full.
>
> In the case of this file, the resume
>   step is failing as file download
>   resuming is not supported on media
>   files within our systems as can be
>   seen by "Accept-Ranges: bytes" not
>   being present within the headers of
>   the HTTP response for this file:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache/2.2
> Content-Type: audio/mpeg
> Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Mar 2011
> 16:27:10 GMT Content-Length: 11226282
> Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 22:00:33 GMT
> X-Varnish: 1663119465 1663112299 Age:
> 73 Connection: keep-alive Via: 1.1
> varnish 172.17.0.138 X-Cache: HIT
> ```
>
> More information on "Accept-Ranges:
>   bytes" can be found in section 14.5
>   here:
>   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
>
> File resume is not supported for this
>   HTTP request as this HTTP request is
>   not being served by Apache, but via
>   the caching Varnish servers within our
>   Media Accelerator cluster.  File
>   resume is supported by Apache
>   inherently.  A list of files cached
>   within our systems by our Varnish
>   servers as well as more information on
>   our Media Accelerator can be found
>   here:
>   http://cloudsites.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/What_is_the_Media_Accelerator_(MA)%3F
>
> HTTP requests are only routed to the
>   Media Accelerator when the HTTP
>   request ends in one of these file
>   extensions.  If a query string is
>   added to the end of the URL or if the
>   URL is made to a different file
>   extension, then the HTTP request is
>   served by Apache as can be seen from
>   the following two sets of headers:
>
> ```
> $ curl -I
> 'http://flex.ekk360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3?1'
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache/2.2
> Content-Type: audio/mpeg Date: Tue, 29
> Mar 2011 21:41:56 GMT Accept-Ranges:
> bytes Connection: Keep-Alive
> Set-Cookie:
> X-Mapping-hpadogcb=018693E96D995C67FDE4A82FC7761170;
> path=/ Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Mar 2011
> 16:27:10 GMT Content-Length: 11226282
>
> $ curl -I
> 'http://flex.ekk360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp_'
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Server:
> Apache/2.2 Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=iso-8859-1 Date: Tue, 29 Mar
> 2011 22:12:29 GMT Transfer-Encoding:
> chunked Connection: Keep-Alive
> Set-Cookie:
> X-Mapping-hpadogcb=381D7664F27DBFFB6452A51D70DEDB28;
> path=/
> ```
>
> In order for this file to be streamed
>   properly from our servers, the Media
>   Accelerator must be bypassed by having
>   the device either use a URL such as
>   "http://flex.ekk360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3?1"
>   or by renaming the file and adding a
>   custom mime type to your site so that
>   the device opens the file with the
>   media player.  An alternative would be
>   to host the file through a CDN such as
>   Cloud Files or Amazon S3.

Answer (score 4):

The difference should be a static file with a defined content length, vs. a shoutcast stream or a server that did not serve a content length with a file.

If the player does not know how large a file is, it cannot retrieve the end to gather metadata (notably, song duration), and present the scrubber for seeking.

[edit]
cURL Header Output:

```
$ curl -I "http://demo.ekklesia360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 21:59:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 16:25:33 GMT
ETag: "8b30001-ab4caa-49fa182643940"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11226282
Connection: close
Content-Type: audio/mpeg

$ curl -I "http://flex.ekk360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 16:27:10 GMT
Content-Length: 11226282
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 21:59:20 GMT
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Via: 1.1 varnish 172.17.0.138
```

On the latter file (via flex), I notice a lack of "Accept-Ranges", and a "Connection" type of "keep-alive".

This tells me that;
(1) that Safari (/QuickTime?) likely will not issue a byte range request for the end of the file in order to read the ID3 data, or;
(2) There is no scrubber because "Connection: keep-alive" means that new data may come down the pipe, so keep the socket open to receive it at some time.

Comment: In both cases it was just a static file, but they were on different servers. I checked the file in question here http://web-sniffer.net/ using iPhone Mobile Safari as the user agent, and it _does_ report a Content-Length.

Comment: @shane From your wifi signal strength, I'd say @vxj might still be right. Does this issue happens every time for a specific file/server? Since it's big file, maybe Safari didn't have the time to fetch the length and it would rather let you play the file, instead of waiting for the information.

Comment: Are you at liberty to divulge the addresses of the files in each of the screenshots?

Comment: I'm not sure which ones those were, but here are some equivalents:
Everything fine: http://demo.ekklesia360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3
Scrubber doesn't appear: http://flex.ekk360.com/judas-and-pilate.mp3

Comment: @Loïc It happens for every file I've tested on this particular platform (Rackspace Cloud Sites). On our Rackspace managed server, and other servers I have tested (Amazon S3, Dreamhost), everything is fine.

Comment: Here is the header information I found, fwiw: http://grabby.info/4d48170023c3f7c8717b42d883a3e019.png

Comment: I didn't get Connection: close for both of them, and this makes me very curious. My mind seems to lock onto the "Connection", "Age", and "Accept-Ranges" headers (or lack thereof).